# Text that changes with the date

Tags: javascript, html, date, text

I have been searching for a while and need help figuring out how to make text change depending on the date. I am traveling and people want to know where I am when, so I was going to post a "where am i now" section on my website.

For example, today I need it to say Dominican Republic, tomorrow Haiti, etc. for the next few weeks.

This is what I have so far but I have no idea if I'm doing it right. Not experienced at all with this!

```
<html>
<head>
<p>
Where am I now?
</p>

<div id="first">Dominican Republic</div>
<div id="second">Haiti</div>
<div id="third">Jamaica</div>

<style>
#first,#second,#third {
    display:none;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
var date=new Date();
var year=date.getFullYear();
var month=date.getMonth();
var day=date.getDate(); // fixed

function SetDivContent() {

    if (year==2017 && month==6) { 
        if (day==8) { 
            $("#first").css("display","block");
        }
        else if (day==9) { 
            $("#second").css("display","block");
        }
        else if (day==10) { 
            $("#third").css("display","block");
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: something like this: https://coderwall.com/p/ouofjg/getting-current-location-with-javascript ?

Comment: @AthMav updated to add, sorry about that!

Comment: Why don't you just have one `<div>` and set appropriate text to it? Also, are you really sure that whoever will be looking at your site will only do so on 8, 9 and 10th of June 2017? What about other dates?

Answer (score 0):

getMonth() is 0 based, yo you need to add +1 to get current month;

```js
var date=new Date();
var year=date.getFullYear();
var month=date.getMonth() + 1;
var day=date.getDate(); // fixed
(function SetDivContent() {

    if (year == 2017 && month == 6) { 
        if (day == 8) {
            $("#first").css("display","block");
        }
        else if (day==9) { 
            $("#second").css("display","block");
        }
        else if (day==10) { 
            $("#third").css("display","block");
        }
    }
})();
```

```css
#first,#second,#third {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
Where am I now?
</p>

<div id="first">Dominican Republic</div>
<div id="second">Haiti</div>
<div id="third">Jamaica</div>
```